# mod_expires ignores webp and avif expiry/cache settings

Tags: apache-2.4, mime-type

I spent an hour or so diagnosing this problem today, and thought the solution might be helpful to others.

Apache's response headers were giving webp and avif files the default expiration (60 seconds), even though I had added the following to my conf-enabled/expires.conf file.

`ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 month"`
`ExpiresByType image/avif "access plus 1 months"`

The same settings worked successfully with other mime types.

I also checked Apache's other cache-related settings, but no changes affected the headers that were returned with these file types.

Apache2.4 was running on an Ubuntu 20.04 server.

Answer (score 0):

webp and avif files (as relatively modern formats) were missing from the server's /etc/mime.types file. Without the base mime type, Apache ignores the ExpiresByType directives that are set.

To fix, do either of the following (or both):

#### 1. Add the following lines to /etc/mime.types

```
 image/webp                       webp
 image/avif                       avif
```

#### 2. Add the following lines to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf

```
 AddType image/webp .webp
 AddType image/avif .avif
```

Either will fix the problem, but the first solution adds the filetypes system-wide, while the second only affects Apache.

File locations correct for Ubuntu Linux server 20.04.